# Is There an Elegant Way to Change URL like "file:///C:/AAA/BBB" to "C:\AAA\BBB"?

Tags: python, path

I want to find an elegant way in Python to change URL like `"file:///C:/AAA/BBB"` to `"C:\AAA\BBB"`.

Comment: What's elegant?

Comment: @ralphtheninja At first, I thought maybe there is a inline function in python to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can `split` then `join`:

```
'\\'.join(s[len('file:///'):].split('/'))
```

Comment: A slight modification to `s[len('file:///'):].replace('/', '\\')` is faster. See the timing results in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49409165/5858851).

Comment: a replace is needed for the double slash to single slash

Comment: @PoornaPrudhvi no, that is just the string representation. Try printing the output.

Comment: Yeah. It's an escape character.

Answer (score 1):

```
    '\\'.join(s.split('/')[3:])
```

Edits :
    spliced out 'file:' and 2 '' from list returned by split. So no need of filter

Comment: Sorry. Please check the edited answer

Comment: 'C:\\AAA\\BBB' is the output need to replace

Comment: Thats because the py interpreter escapes some chars. Use print and check

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.replace()`:

```
s = "file:///C:/AAA/BBB"
s_new = s.replace("file:///", "").replace("/", "\\")
print(s_new)
#C:\AAA\BBB
```

**Timing Results**

On my laptop running python 2.x

```
#@liliscent's solution
%%timeit
'\\'.join(s[len('file:///'):].split('/'))
#1000000 loops, best of 3: 603 ns per loop

#@pault's solution
%%timeit
s_new = s.replace("file:///", "").replace("/", "\\")
#1000000 loops, best of 3: 555 ns per loop

#combination of both above
%%timeit
s[len('file:///'):].replace('/', '\\')
#1000000 loops, best of 3: 396 ns per loop

#Arnab Mukherjee's solution
%%timeit
'\\'.join(s.split('/')[3:])
#1000000 loops, best of 3: 696 ns per loop
```

Comment: Could you re run my edited soln. I changed it a little from the one you used